# Android SDK Source Tag

Tags: android, git, sdk, repository

Once you select which device version you will be developing on, what is the different between the tagged versions in git repository?

Example:
android-2.1_r1
android-sdk-2.1_r1

Is checking out one more correct than the other for debugging/stepping through code? Been using the tags with "-sdk" in name, just curious what the difference between the two are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `git diff android-2.1_r1 android-sdk-2.1_r1`

Comment: Lol, guess that answers it. Absolutely no difference! Thanks.